# How can default screenshot be defined for Google Play app/game?

Tags: android, facebook, google-play, google-play-games

how can one set which screenshot will be displayed when a link to a game/app in Google Play is shared?

Example: I want to share in Facebook a link to my new game:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.dragonslabs.battlesnake

What appears on the wall, is the screenshot for the alternative movement settings, which is good to gain basic understanding what are the supported movement options, but by far now that I want to show as first impression of the game.

Is there any way to specify which screenshot appears - either via the share link, or to specify in the Developer Console?

Thanks!

Comment: No, you can not specify those values any more when sharing a Google Play store URL, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog#params – if anywhere, this would have to be configured in the GP store, because that’s where Facebook fetches the meta data from.

Comment: Thanks, this narrows the search area :)
Any idea how to specify it in Google Play store / Developer Console?
I found several link giving some overview of the console, but none that address my issue...